# Any way to detect if any animation is currently running on an Android View Property?

Tags: android

Is there any global list of animators currently active that we can access? Or if I know the property and object which I suspect may be animating right now, can I check it?

The use case is that I want to check if a fragment is currently in the middle of a transition. The `FragmentManager` is initializing the animator, so I don't have access to it. I know I could override `onCreateAnimator`, but that function is limited with regards to knowing when it's pushing or popping on the backstack so I'm unable to know which animation to create.

Comment: How is it limited?  The final parameter is the R.anim ID of the animator that you want  to create for the given transaction.

Comment: You're right. In my initial tests I found it to always be 0 but when I retested now it's as you say. This would probably be my soution then.